# On edit of a row in google sheet execute a formula on the data of set row and paste the result of the formula in the first column of set row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am making a **database of items**. As items will be edited by many people I would like **formulas to be hidden** so people would not manipulate them easily compromising the database.

I tried to edit a script that recognizes any **edit within a row** and execute a **formula** on column values of set row pasting the result of the formula in column A of set row.

As I am very new to google app script I don't know how to proceed and many examples I have looked through don't do what I want.

I hope what I have written is clear.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here is the code I wrote:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Your sheet params
  var sheetName = "Sheet1";
  var ModifiedColumnIndex = 1;
  var ModifiedColumnLetter = 'A';


  var range = e.range; // range just edited
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() !== sheetName) {
    return;
  }

  // If the column isn't our source column
  if (range.getColumn() != ModifiedColumnIndex) { 
    var row = range.getRow();
  // Formula to be executed on the edited rows cells  
    var formula = sheet + row [lower[trim(B&" "&C&" "&D&" "&E&" "&F&" "&G&" ["&I&"]"]])
    var ModifiedRange = sheet.getRange(ModifiedColumnLetter + row.toString());
  //Inserting formula into column A                               
    ModifiedRange.setValue(formula);
  };
 };
```

Comment: This line doesn't make any sense to me; `var formula = sheet + row [lower[trim(B&" "&C&" "&D&" "&E&" "&F&" "&G&" ["&I&"]"]])`

Comment: A formula needs to begin with "=".

Comment: Thank you for looking through the issue. In this line and last line I am stuck. I don't think I can write a formula within the code like I did, even with  "= " sign. Perhaps the formula I have written should be translated to Google Apps Script. I put in a sample of formula I would like to use there in the supplied code.

Comment: Hi, is there anybody else that can help with this issue?

Comment: There's something wrong in your formula I think. But I avoid the use of formulas so I can't help you there.

Comment: As others have said, your formula is THE problem. Its not clear what you actually want to do here, nor the kind of values (text, numeric, date, etc) that are in those cells ). Please share a spreadsheet with some sample data and an example of the formula that you want to create.

Comment: I understand the problems with lines 18 and 21. Trash both and re-think. **We need to know the actual formula**. There are (at least) two approaches. 1) build the "formula" in the script, insert it in the target cell using `setFormula`, then copy/'paste values only' in the target cell; or 2) calculate the value within the script and insert it directly into the target cell using `setValue` (my preferred approach). Either way, you have to `getValues` at some stage, and this is one reason why your "formula" variable is not working.